# How to detect edit button actions in UITabbarController(More) iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, edit, uitabbaritem

I have 6 tabbar items in my iphone app. 4 tabbar items visible directly and other 2 items in More tabitem. There user can change the tabbar items by clicking Edit button. Is it possible to detect the Edit button functionality? If it is possible means how can i detect that? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `UITabBarControllerDelegate`:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

It's got methods such as `tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:` which I think does what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I will accept your answer after 8 mins. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. In general with this sort of thing, think delegate. More often than not there's a delegate method for situations where you want to be told about interaction with a certain view controller.